# Mailchimp popup not working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, email, mailchimp

I am trying to add a mailchimp popup to my magento site. So in the footer.phtml I added this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function showMailingPopUp() {
  require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {
  L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us16.list-manage.com","uuid":"34cc754j80ba938d52dc3e486f",
  "lid":"0b245fgj05b2"
  })
 })
 document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
 };
 jQuery(function() {
   jQuery(".open-popup").on('click', function() {
     showMailingPopUp();
     console.log('test');
   });
 });
});

</script>
```

But I am getting an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

If I remove `require` I see `test` in my console when I click the popup link but no popup from mailchimp to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you move your code outside of the `jQuery(document).ready` function?

Comment: @user7290573 I have the same result.